# Deploy Pytidylib module in aws lambda by using Lamda Layers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to deploy pytidylib python module into AWS lambda function by using layers .
I have created the path as described in aws docs and created new layer.
Now the code of pytidylib needs some libraries from /usr/lib but i have installed libraries in /python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ , so to resolve this i added the path in environ PATH of aws linux server platform , but still the issue is not resolved.
Below is my code :-

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
"""Read  file from s3 on trigger."""
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    print(sys.platform)
    ld_library_path = os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"]
    print("old ld_library_path is ",ld_library_path)
    ld_library_path = ld_library_path + 
   ":/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/"
    os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = ld_library_path
    print("ld_library_path after set is 
    ",os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"])
  
ld_library_path after set is  /var/lang/lib:/lib64:/usr/lib64:/var/runtime:/var/runtime/lib:/var/task:/var/task/lib:/opt/lib:/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
```

I want to understand is there any way i can make this work through some changes in code and make the pytidylib module run through layers .
Below is the error:-

```
[ERROR] OSError: Could not load libtidy using any of these names: 
libtidy,libtidy.so,libtidy-0.99.so.0,cygtidy-0-99-0,tidylib,libtidy.dylib,tidy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 68, in lambda_handler
document, errors = tidy_document(doc)
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tidylib/tidy.py", line 222, in tidy_document
return get_module_tidy().tidy_document(text, options)
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tidylib/tidy.py", line 234, in get_module_tidy
_tidy = Tidy()
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tidylib/tidy.py", line 99, in __init__
+ ",".join(lib_names))
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to **replicate**  your issue and for me `Pytidylib` layer works as expected.

This is the way I used to construct the layer, in case you want to give it a try. It involves a  **docker tool** described in the recent **AWS blog**:

- [How do I create a Lambda layer using a simulated Lambda environment with Docker?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/)

I created `Pytidylib` layer as follows:

1. Create empty folder, e.g. `mylayer`.
2. Go to the folder and create `requirements.txt` file with the content of

```
Pytidylib
```

3. Run the following docker command (may adjust python version to your needs):

```
docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task "lambci/lambda:build-python3.8" /bin/sh -c "pip install -r requirements.txt -t python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/; exit"
```

4. Create layer as zip:

```
zip -r pytidylayer.zip python > /dev/null
```

5. Create lambda layer based on `pytidylayer.zip` in the AWS Console. Don't forget to specify `Compatible runtimes` to `python3.8`.
6. Add the layer to the lambda and test using the following lambda function:

```
import json
import  tidylib 

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    print(dir(tidylib))
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

The function executed correctly:

```
['PersistentTidy', 'Tidy', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'release_tidy_doc', 'sink', 'tidy', 'tidy_document', 'tidy_fragment']
```

Comment: I tried the same way as you described but as soon as i implement the pytidylib by  "document, errors = tidy_document(doc)" it breaks and gives the same error as above .

Comment: @user190549 I only tested if it loads. Don't have any documents to test more.

Comment: do you know how can we add these libraries in /usr/lib of lambda server

Comment: @user190549 You can't modify these folders. The only alternative is to try without layers, and just bundle the `Pytidylib` with your deployment package. But if it requires some os-level packages in `/usr/lib` you won't be able to add them there.

Comment: okay ill try with the deployment package, Thanks for help :)

Comment: @user190549 Sorry, could not help more. Let me know how it will go.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding path of the tidy library (libtidy.so.5.2.0) into the environment variable of LD_LIBRARY_PATH of linux server

For me library was pre installed in ubuntu 18.04 server in /usr/lib .Copy the library from this path ,place it inside the tidylib folder create a zip, and follow the steps of lambda-layers creation .